# Java wont uninstall on mac OS(Mojave)

Tags: java, uninstallation, macos-mojave, java-11

i have followed this procedure as per documentation by java

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

but still when i perform java -version in terminal

```
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

when i try to remove jdk this comes up

```
rm -r ~/"Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java" 
rm: /Users/<>/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java: No such file or directory
```

i am unable to locate java control panel in sys preferences(Even when i first installed java on machine it didnt show on up sys preferences), nor in finder library

unable to figure out what's the issue

Comment: I recommend to move this question to https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: shash678: its already in system, i am having hard time getting rid of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the correct location of Java using the below command in the terminal

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

and then delete the folder using sudo rm -rf

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

this comes up

Comment: Just remove the directory using rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-* if you don't need any version of Java in your system

Comment: that's the issue, i cant see that folder in library

Comment: rm: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk: Permission denied

Comment: it says permission denied

Comment: use sudo rm -rf

Comment: @SiddharthKoya does sudo help?

Comment: but i dont understand how come that location didnt show up in library but we were successful in uninstalling from terminal

Comment: may be it is not accessible because you don't have permissions as a normal user. It should have been visible if you had used sudo